# make a building as marker in augmented reality

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, metaio

i want to make an augmented reality which the building as a marker. in my research there is object as a marker for an augmented reality, i didnt found that object is a building.
. I want to know that is this possible that i can use  real object (building) as a marker in augmented reality, If yes then would you suggest me that which any sdk for which will help me to build this in iPhone and android like Vuforia. 
how to make a building as marker? what app that use for that ?
please help me. thank you

Comment: Please mark an answer if question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia is perfect for this my friend. It's completely up to you on which SDK you chose but I use vuforia so I woul suggest that. There is no app for specifically making buildings markers, instead they are methods to make it possible. These are just my views on how this can be achieved and as far as my knowledge goes, it should definitely work. There are two ways of doing this:-

- **Using the** [**Vuforia Object Scanner**](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/tool): This is a slightly expensive approach. Since buildings cannot be directly placed under the camera for this app to function, you could get the builduings achitectural drawings and 3D Print a miniature version of it, so that it is now easier to scan.
- **Using MultiTarget**: Well, this is basically very straightforward, the picture of the builing (that is the Front View, Side View and Plan) are uploaded into the [Vuforia Target Manager](https://developer.vuforia.com/target-manager) and can be made into a Multitarget object and this can then be used for various applications.